# Symbols in Star Trek: Planet of Judgment book

Tags: star-trek, star-trek-tos, symbols

I recently bought [Planet of Judgment](https://memory-alpha.fandom.com/wiki/Planet_of_Judgment), a book in the Star Trek - The Original Series universe. It begins with Captain Kirk and the others (Bones, Spock, ...) getting stranded on a rogue planet and not being able to communicate with the Enterprise. However, they find a way by making some symbols which can be seen through a kind of telescope from the Enterprise. These are the symbols and their meaning:

[image: Image of the book]

Have these symbols ever occurred (or re-occurred) in a Star Trek series (I only saw TOS and TAS) or are they just the imagination of the writer?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

I bought that when it first came out (yes, I'm that old) and wondered about that. Of course, we didn't have the internet back then so I just took it on faith.

**As it happens, they are real.**

I don't recall them ever coming up again but they do seem to conform to actual symbols adopted by the Civil Aeronautics Administration in the mid-20th Century.

[**Google Books**](https://books.google.co.uk/books?id=RSgDAAAAMBAJ&pg=PA135&lpg=PA135&dq=symbols%20downed%20airman&source=bl&ots=ggWrHGTilX&sig=uuLFIGrfrVGL5DUcjNcchCbmfEo&hl=en&sa=X&sqi=2&ved=0ahUKEwigtNqlzd7OAhUC2RoKHaP3BREQ6AEINzAE#v=onepage&q=symbols%20downed%20airman&f=false) copy of Popular Science April 1948

[image]
[image]

..and here's another from what is, [apparently](http://www.usmilitariaforum.com/forums/index.php?/topic/190406-landing-codes-on-1944-jungle-first-aid-pouch/), a PSK 2 USN issue medical/ emergency kit probably from the early 1960s

[image]

---

As it happens the author, [**Joe Haldeman**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Joe_Haldeman) (**that Joe Haldeman**) served as a combat engineer in Vietnam so there's a good chance he would have had personal knowledge of these.

Comment: That looks very promising! The first one is an exact copy, the second one is almost the same (and I presume the S is just a way to make clear that the shuttles are damaged) and the third one is almost an exact copy but I presume that the tilde works as a negative symbol.

Comment: Any idea what the thinking was behind the "+" sign?  It makes sense that the real-world references don't use it, since it would look the same as an "X" from the air.  It seems odd that the author would choose it.

Comment: @JohnWalthour Give the deciphered meaning, I would interpret it as a cross, not as a plus sign.

Comment: Ahhh that'd do it